# Possible to access scope items that ng-repeat creates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm under the impression that ng-repeat creates a new scope for each element in the array/object.

Is it possible to access these new scopes that the ng-repeat creates from the controller? For example if you know the index?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the scopes?

Comment: So I have a list which is put into the ng-repeat. Inside each ng-repeat there is a button with ng-click, which calls a function. My idea was I could put the $index inside the ng-click="function($index)", and then have access to items in that specific ng-repeat scope. Long-story short, I need a way to get all the items inside the current ng-repeat index on click.

Comment: Just pass the item will work: `ng-click="function(item)"`

Comment: You can define the function on the parent scope and pass in the item and the index if needed.

Comment: Thanks! Will this also pass the items if there were a nested ng-repeat in the ng-repeat also?

Answer (score 9):

Check the console of this demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvhtvy69/).

`console.log` the scope, there are two attributes `$$childHead` and `$$childTail`. They are the first and last child scopes created by `ng-repeat`.

After getting the first child scope `$$childHead`, you can traverse to get other `ng-repeat` scope objects through `$$nextSibling` and `$$prevSibling`.

> Note: these attributes start with `$$`, which indicate that they are `private` Angular variables. I suppose they are not intended to be used directly.

If you use `ng-repeat` like `<div ng-repeat="item in items"></div>`, you can use `ng-click="dealWithItem(item, $index)"` to pass this item to a function defined in the controller:

```
$scope.dealWithItem = function (item, index) {
    // console.log(item);
}
```

It works for nested `ng-repeat` as well: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvhtvy69/1/).

Comment: This is very helpful, appreciate it. Will this still work with nested ng-repeat's too inside the ng-repeat"item = items"?

Comment: Thanks for your help Joy. How would grabbing nested ng-repeat data work if the click function isn't inside the child ng-repeat? For example... <div ng-repeat="item in items"><div ng-repeat="child in children"></div><a ng-click="function(item)">Get all data</a></div>

Comment: If you mean getting the `children`, it is obviously on the item `item.children`.

Comment: This doesn't work if children is a completely separate object/array

Answer (score 3):

When I tried Joy's answer, I got undefined for the item variable at the console.  But there is an easier way to do it.

html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in names">
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right" ng-click="dealWithItem()">{{name.first_name}}</button>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.dealWithItem = function () {
    console.log(this.name.first_name);
}
```

this.name will have all of the attributes associated with $scope.names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$parent` as an argument of your function to access these scopes:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div ng-click="doSomethingWithItem(item, $parent)"></div>
</div>
```